# Why do my floats insist on staying integers?

Tags: c++, floating-point

I am reading in several integers, which represent the year, julian day, hour, and minutes.  I am trying to convert them to fractional days.

```
int YYYY, JJJ, HH, MM;

float datenumber = (YYYY*360.0f)+(JJJ*1.0f)+((HH*1.0f)+(MM/60.0f))/24.0f;
```

Using the values of `2001, 083, 22, 32` I should get a result of `724043.939`.  Instead I get `724044`.

I have all the ints cast as floats. Why do they stay as integers?

*edit* Yes, I was displaying the output with cout. setprecision resolved the problem, thank you.

Comment: How are you viewing the final value; debugger, `printf()` ?

Comment: How are you printing the result out? It's possible that the problem is in your print statement

Comment: According to [my test](http://ideone.com/KhmMZ), `printf` displays the expected result, but `cout` displays the "wrong" value.

Comment: Be warned though about dangers of using floats for arithmetic, they are imprecise.

Comment: I am trying to convert to serial numbers, as in Matlab's datenum function, so I can easily compare a time series, and fill in missing minute and seconds. Is there a better way to do this? Are doubles more precise than floats?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not in your number or your calculation.  It is only in the way you are displaying it.  `cout` has decided that 6 digits is enough for you.  Use `setprecision` if you want more.

```
std::cout << std::setprecision(10) << datenumber;
```

[demo](http://ideone.com/E6AIP)

Comment: No, there's something fishier going on here. Check this out: http://codepad.org/TfRlPfOh

Comment: @Jacob, you get that output because as a `float`, the value of the variable *really is* 432000. It doesn't have enough precision to hold the rest of the value. See [my exact-float page](http://www.cs.wisc.edu/~rkennedy/exact-float?number=432000.0034722222).

Comment: It wasn't `cout` that decided 6 was enough; it was the C++ standard. Six is the default precision for any new `basic_ios` descendant.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do **TWO** things:

1. Set your precision to the max (`cout.setprecision(16)`)
2. Convert to `double` (`double dateNumber` and `YYYY*360.0`)

Comment: That's what [my test](http://ideone.com/KhmMZ) does. There must be more to it than that.

Comment: @RobKennedy: I think changing it to double and changing the precision should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you've got some more code that does the casting elsewhere, you're doing your cast after you've done the equation, so you are getting a float back, but using the ints in the equation before your cast drops the decimals.

Why not declare them as floats initially?

```
float YYYY, JJJ, HH, MM;
```

Comment: He's using `float` constants as the other operands to `*` and `/` so the `int`s are promoted to `float`s before those operations are done. That means that what you mentioned is not a problem. EDIT: What Dan F says below is correct.

Comment: Doesn't it always do floating point arithmetic if a float is involved? therefore `int*float` will not truncate unless you cast...

Comment: Ah yes, should have known...my bad

Answer (score 0):

The following may be the reason-
1.May be you are printing them wrongly.
2.Dividing by an integer,use float instead.

Example-Instead of dividing by 200 divide by 200.0

Answer (score 0):

Judging from your input and output values in the example you provided in Benjamin's answer, I am willing to bet that the issue is just floating point precision. Just because you declare something as a float, doesn't mean it can handle any size number. The problem lies in the fact that your year component (1200*360=432000) is WAY larger than your MM component(5/60/24=.00347222). The decimal portion from the MM part is just ignored because floats aren't that accurate. Try adding .000001 to 123456789 as a float and see what your output is